# Why does my WLAN stop working when I plug in my HDTV?

Tags: wifi, display, displayport, hdmi

I'm facing a strange problem where my WLAN suddenly stops working the moment I plug in my HDTV into my MacBook 13" (mid-2010) using an HDMI to DisplayPort adapter.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like [I'm not the only one](http://ask.metafilter.com/145449/Mini-displayport-stops-80211g-from-working-how-why) who is fighting this issue. That guy uses the same router (Linksys WRT54GL) as I do and just switched the WLAN channel to solve the problem.

This does also solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a shot in the dark but have you tried a different cable?  Maybe the one you're using is damaged and is shorting something somewhere which is affecting the wireless antenna.  It is definitely a weird problem by the sounds of it but you could try a couple of tests by first using a different cable, then using a different TV with each cable and see if they all produce the same result.  If they do then it might be worth getting Apple to take a look at your DisplayPort socket if you're under warranty or a good repair shop.  I've seen weird things happen to computers with dodgy USB cables so there's a chance it's something like that.